# nor query in Mongoose not working with _id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Ok, so I have a project set up with MEAN.js, which uses Mongoose.

I want to do a search of all users in MongoDB where either the email or displayName field matches a regex and the _id does not match a certain set of IDs.

here's the query I'm doing:

```
var re = new RegExp(req.body.pattern, 'i');
var memberIDs = '';

req.body.members.forEach(function(member){ //members have a user field which is an ObjectID
    memberIDs += (member.user + ' ');
});
memberIDs += req.user._id;


 User.find().or([{ 'displayName': { $regex: re }},
                 { 'email': { $regex: re }}])
               .nor([{'_id' : memberIDs}])
               .select('displayName email')
               .exec(function(err, users) {
                    if(err){
                        res.status(400).send({
                            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                        });
                    }else{              
                        res.json(users);
                    } 
                });
    };
```

This doesn't work and the message I get from the error is just an empty string.
The query works fine without the .nor() method. Can I not use the _id field like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doing this all wrong. Here's the first really wrong thing:

```
req.body.members.forEach(function(member){ 
    //members have a user field which is an ObjectID
    memberIDs += (member.user + ' ');
});
```

This is just joining a "space delimited" string which is not valid for any part of the query syntax.

I think a little confusion comes here from some of the forms such as `.select()` that allow such things to be done. But as general arguments this is not valid.

I can also guess you have a different language background than JavaScript, and also not with dynamically typed languages. If you had then you probably wouldn't be reaching for the "helper methods" and would have just constructed the query object dynamically in code, which is something people familiar with dynamic languages are used to.

So you want a "data structure" here. And the valid operator you want it [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) which takes a "list" or "array" of arguments:

```
var excludeList = [];

req.body.members.forEach(function(member){ 
    //members have a user field which is an ObjectID
    excludeList.push( member.user );
});

// And finally the current id value
excludeList.push( req.user._id );

User.find(
   { 
       "$or": [
            { "displayName": { "$regex": re } },
            { "email": { "$regex": re } }
       ],
       "_id": { "$nin": excludeList }
   },
   'displayName email',
   function(err,users) {
       // work with results here

   }
);
```

If you really insist on using the "helper methods", then you join them up like this:

```
User.find().or([
    { "displayName": { "$regex": re } },
    { "email": { "$regex": re } }
]).where("_id").nin(excludeList)
.select("displayName email")
.exec(function(err,users) {
   // work with content here
});
```

As long as you have not overridden the "type" of the `_id` field in the schema definition then conversions will happen from strings to `ObjectId` values automatically.

Comment: Didn't manage to edit the previous comment.
The reason I used a space delimeted string was because that's what the mongoose docs said for the nor operator.

You're correct in saying I come from a different background but had I known I could have constructed the query object like that, I would have done so, that's probably because I'm a newcomer to MongoDB and Mongoose. I also didn't know about the $nin operator. 
The mongoose docs use the helper methods a lot, is there any reason why I'm better off without them?

Comment: @lokias This is very much what I said if you read through the content in the answer. This comes from a misinterpretation of what is meant by arguments as a "space delimited string" or as provided in object notation. If you note all of the above, then the "field selection" portion of the query statement is always written as mongoose interprets the "string" rather than the object form `{ "displayName": 1, "email": 1 }` which it interprets to. This is not the same as criteria where you start a list. ie `"_id": "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"` as seven separate values. That is just wrong, so where you went wrong